# Prove that the function T is a projection.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a projection on the vector space $V$.

Prove that:

- $I - T$ is a projection
- $V = \ker(I-T) \oplus \mathrm{im}(I-T)$

How do I show that $(I - T)^2 = (I - T)$.
I think $I$ is every thing that's not in $T$. So then null space and the range combined will give the projection.

Comment: $(I-T)^2=I-2T+T^2=\cdots $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$I$ denotes the identity on $V$.

Let $v\in V$. $(I-T)(v) = v - T(v)$. Applying $I-T$ again, we obtain $v - T(v) - T(v) + T^2(v)$, and by assumption on $T$ this is $v-T(v)$ so that $(I-T)^2 = I-T$, and $I-T$ is a projection.

For the second one, I give you a hint. Let $v \in V$. Then $v = v - T(v) + T(v)$. What can you get from this?

Comment: So you combined the kernel and image which leads to v, wow that's clever thanks :).